# How do I combine two lines into one list?

Tags: python

I have a file(text.txt) which looks like this:

```
I went to the pool yesterday.

The water there was freezing and I caught a cold
```

I am reading this file in and removing the extra new line in between. However, upon doing so, these two lines are being put into separate lists. Something like this:

```
[[u'i', u'went', u'to', u'the', u'pool', u'yesterday'], [u'the', u'water', u'there', u'was', u'freezing', u'and', u'i', u'caught', u'a', u'cold']]
```

How can I ensure that these two lines are put into one list of lists instead?
I am looking at something like this:

```
[[u'i', u'went', u'to', u'the', u'pool', u'yesterday', u'the', u'water', u'there', u'was', u'freezing', u'and', u'i', u'caught', u'a', u'cold']]
```

This is my code so far to remove extra space.

```
lines=[line for line in punc if line]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
lines = sum((line for line in punc if line), [])
```

It takes the sum of all of the lines.  Normally, `sum()` works by adding each item to an original value of `0`, but when you give it something else, `[]`, it adds everything to that.

Comment: This gives me all the sentences in one list. How can I ensure it follows a list of list format as shown above. I need it in that format for processing

Comment: Put `[` before and `]` after `sum(...)`

Answer (score 1):

For your desired output, you don't need to iterate lines at all.  You can just read the entire input and split:

```
>>> with open('text.txt') as f:
...     words = [f.read().split()]
```